# Basic C / K&R 2.7 / Character displayed as diamond regardless of definition?

Tags: c, arrays, character

I am trying to create input and outputs to check some functions in K&R and any modifications of them.  For atoi on Section 2.7 (unchanged but for the name), I added a print function and a sample character for it to convert.  The program seems to work except the character string (the value to be tested) appears as a diamond no matter what I do (i.e., regardless of the character string, GGGAAAZ as given or other entries), and then the integer value is always  zero.  Is this a compiler issue (and if so, fixes?) or am I overlooking something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char s[] = "GGGAAAZ";
    int n;
    n = antoi(s);
    printf("The char was %c\n", s);
    printf("The int is %d \n", n);

    return 0;
}

/* atoi: convert s to integer; name changed to antoi because */
int antoi(char s[])
{
int i, n;
n = 0;
for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '0'; ++i)
n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
return n;
}
```

The diamond persists whether I do something like "GGGAAAZ" or define s[] ='a', 'b', 'c'

Thanks!

Comment: `s[i] <= '0'` --> `s[i] <= '9'`. Also `printf("The char was %c\n", s);` --> `printf("The char was %s\n", s);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues.

1. printing a string using `printf` should use `%s` as the format. `%c` is for a single character, but you are passing a pointer to a character array.
2. (as said in the comments) `s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '0'` is the same as `s[i] == '0'`. You should put `s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'`
3. You are passing "GGGAAAZ" to the function, that isn't going to be converted into anything but 0 by your code.